# Adding two columns in pandas with a character between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have 7 columns in my csv.
I want to join the first two columns and I have done that by converting the csv into dataframe and :

```
df["patient_week"] = df["Patient"] + df["Weeks"].astype(str)
```

What this gives me is the values of both columns joined as it should :
But I want the values to be joined with a "_" between them.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Data:

```
   col2 col3
id      
1   3   8
2   4   3
3   5   9
```

Code:

```
df['New']=df['col2'].astype(str)+"_"+df['col3'].astype(str)
df
```

Result:

```
   col2 col3 New
id          
1   3   8   3_8
2   4   3   4_3
3   5   9   5_9
```

In your case:

```
df["patient_week"] = df["Patient"] +"_"+ df["Weeks"].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

```
df["patient_week"] = df[["Patient","Weeks"]].astype('str').agg('_'.join,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use '_' string between them

Comment: How would you *simply '_' string between them* can you explain?

Comment: df["patient_week"] = df["Patient"] + '_' +  df["Weeks"].astype(str)

Comment: Much better if you post an answer, than words. Easier to understand